# Explain this pickup line: "If Bangkok invaded Djibouti, would Greece help?"

Tags: pronunciation, puns, offensive-language, jokes

I was at an Model UN conference and often notes like the following get passed. As I'm not a native speaker, I assume that this has to do with some pronunciational issue. Can you please explain what's so funny about this sentence? (Djibouti seemed to be often used in such context.)

> If Bangkok invaded Djibouti would Greece help?

Comment: Reminds me of the joke "If I told you you had a beautiful body, would you hold it against me?"

Comment: Hmm... what's the site policy on vulgarities? Obviously the poster didn't know when they asked, but this is clearly PG 18 (or 15 at least!) - not that I personally have a problem with it.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't call this a pickup line.  YMMV

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The punning here is obscene. It means

> If bang cock invaded your booty, would grease help?

```
cock = penis
booty = ass 
grease = lubricant
```

Comment: One more: "Bang" means "intercourse." Also, this is not a pickup line. At least, I HOPE it isn't!

Comment: @horatio: at least, let it not be a successful one

Comment: Sounds like something Stifler would say..

Comment: @User42 next question is, do the guys at Model UN really have nothing else to do?

Comment: I assume this note was written by the Model Dominique Strauss-Kahn.